# Confidence interval for Weibull distribution

Tags: r, distribution, confidence-interval, weibull

I have wind data that I'm using to perform extreme value analysis (calculate return levels). I'm using *R* with packages 'evd', 'extRemes' and 'ismev'.

I'm fitting GEV, Gumbel and Weibull distributions, in order to estimate the return levels (RL) for some period T.
For the GEV and Gumbel cases, I can get RL's and Confidence Intervals using the *extRemes::return.level()* function.

Some code:

```
require(ismev)
require(MASS)

data(wind)
x = wind[, 2]
rperiod = 10

fit <- fitdistr(x, 'weibull')
s <- fit$estimate['shape']
b <- fit$estimate['scale']

rlevel <- qweibull(1 - 1/rperiod, shape = s, scale = b)

## CI around rlevel
## ci.rlevel = ??
```

But for the Weibull case, I need some help to generate the CI's.

Comment: You have provided a sketchy description of what you have done but this is a coding forum and you are expected to post data and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the excruciatingly correct answer will be that the joint confidence region is an ellipse or some bent-sausage shape but you can extract variance estimates for the parameters from the fit object with the `vcov` function and then build standard errors for which +/- 1.96 SE's should be informative:

```
> sqrt(vcov(fit)["shape", "shape"])
[1] 0.691422
> sqrt(vcov(fit)["scale", "scale"])
[1] 1.371256

> s +c(-1,1)*sqrt(vcov(fit)["shape", "shape"])
[1] 6.162104 7.544948
> b +c(-1,1)*sqrt(vcov(fit)["scale", "scale"])
[1] 54.46597 57.20848
```

The usual way to calculate a CI for a single parameter is to assume Normal distribution and use theta+/- 1.96*SE(theta). In this case, you have two parameters so doing that with both of them would give you a "box", the 2D analog of an interval. The truly correct answer would be something more complex in the 'scale'-by-'shape' parameter space and might be most easily achieved with simulation methods, unless you have a better grasp of theory than I have.

Comment: So now i can calculate qweibull_inf and qweibull_hi using these values?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand your terminology here.

Comment: I have the CI's for shape and scale. Can i just plug these to calculate weibull quantiles using qweibull(p, shape, scale)?

Comment: there is a strong smell of homework in the air. At least try a Bonferroni correction if you are using separate confidence intervals for your variables.

Comment: @Fernando: I still do not understand what you want, so I cannot tell if the code would deliver an appropriate output. You do not yet seem to understand that a box is a two dimensional confidence _region_ (defined by its 4 corners). I do not understand what sort of Bonferroni correction might be advised by Ferdinand. I do not see multiple testing being done. Estimating two parameters is not the same as multiple comparisons.

Comment: I'll explain better: i can calculate q for a given T: q = qweibull(1 - 1/T, s, b). Now i want a confidence interval for q (the return.level function calculates this for gev and gumbel models). You teach me how to get CI's around s, and b. Now, what im supposed to do with these values to get q_inf and q_hi? Thanks!

Comment: You are asking for two values and I am saying that is the wrong mental model for what is going on here. Please explain what you hope to do with these two values.

Comment: @DWin, as you said, the question is unclear and there is a lot of guessing on our side. AFAIU, he has 2 unknown parameters, shape and scale, so his parametric space is bidimensional. From his observations, he computes a point estimate for the pair `(s,b)`, and you suggested two independent CI's around these estimates. The bonferroni correction is this context builds a (1-alpha) confidence region in `(s,b)`-space as a rectangle using (1-alpha/2) CI's for `s` and `b`. That is the correction, because (1-alpha/2)^2 ~= (1-alpha).

Comment: The exact approach is to invert the test used in `fitdistr` to get all values of `s` and `b` that are not rejected. This will probably *not* be a rectangle, might not even be a contiguous region. Then apply the function `q = qweibull(1 - 1/T, s, b)` to all `(s,b)` in this region, and keep the range of values `q` found.

Comment: I did not suggest two independent CI's. I indicated that the correct approach would be to consider these as dependent and that the true region would be more complex. I do not think bonferroni is needed and consider it rather tangential to the matter at hand.

Comment: @DWin, No criticism intended. It's clear from your answer that the "suggestion" to use the independent CI's is to be taken with a grain of salt. I was trying to advised him that, if he was planning to build a 2D box with the separate CI's, then he should compute (1-alpha/2) CI's instead of (1-alpha) CI's. As for "being tangential", I must disagree, for the reasons explained above.

Comment: Who knows,it might work. It woud be interesting to construct dependent bootstrapped estimates of shape and scale and then construct a two-d density. I expect there to be extensions out to the shape and scale directions which would widen the extremes for the "return" estimates. It might be of similar magnitude as the Bonferroni adjustment but I think that would be more of a  accident than something predicted by theory.

Comment: Thanks guys. This discussion is a little ahead of my knowledge, but i already managed to solve it - just report the parameters CI is enough for me.